# Add field formatter settings to all field formats

Tags: entities

I would like to be able to modify the display of any field formatter. To to this I think the best approach is to add settings to all field display formats. Alternatively, I could create my own field formatter that applies to all field types and then show the default display formats within my own display settings.

For example say I want to have a field display settings checkbox that enables a div around the display of any field.

Comment: Why not just override field.tpl.php and implement `hook_preprocess_field()` to make your changes?

Comment: Thank you Clive. I'm making a module to manipulate the display of fields so this really needs to be done through the field interface.  

I've found that there's hook_field_formatter_info_alter which looks like you can use it to add your own settings to a formatter but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to work this out.

hook_field_formatter_info_alter() isn't properly implemented in Drupal 7. There is however the field_formatter_settings module which exposes two hooks:

- hook_field_formatter_settings_form_alter()
- hook_field_formatter_settings_summary_alter()

https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_settings

Using the dependent modules (e.g. field_delimiter) as examples I was able to achieve what I needed.